# Object oriented design in python

Tags: python

I have a base functionality

```
 class Foo(object):


   def method(self):
       return True # or False based on custom logic for each class that will implement this class

   def almost_common_method(self, params, force):
      if self.method():
         params.bleh = 'foo bar'
      else:
        params.bleh = 'not foo bar'
      if force:
         foobar = some_foo_bar(model_name = 'foo bar')
       else:
         default = Default()


   def common_method(self, params, force):
     return self.almost_common_method(params, force)
```

So, I am thinking of making a base class... where method raises NotImplementedError
I implement the common_method() in the base class as this will be shared across all the classes inheriting the base class?
But is there a way to define `almost_common_method()` in base class.. THe variable names are common.. but it is the string assignments which will differ.. across different implementations of this base class.?

Comment: Might want to fix the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good fit for the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  Break the string out into a separate method:

```
class FooBase(object):
    @property
    def bleh(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
        # consider making this an abstract base class with the abc module
    def almost_common_method(self, params, force):
        params.bleh = self.bleh
        if force:
            foobar = some_foo_bar(model_name = 'foo bar')
         else:
            default = Default()

class Foo(FooBase):
    @property
    def bleh(self):
        if self.method():
            return 'foo bar'
        else:
            return 'not foo bar'
```

Each subclass can override `bleh` with its own separate implementation.

The use of `@property` is optional, and should generally be used only if you expect `bleh` to act like an attribute (that is, it doesn't change "by magic", fetching it is relatively cheap and free of visible side effects, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Define `almost_common_method` in the base class as well, but parameterize the values you assign using class attributes:

```
class Base(object):
    BLEH_IF_METHOD = 'foo bar'
    BLEH_IF_NOT_METHOD = 'not foo bar'

    def almost_common_method(self, params, force):
        if self.method():
            params.bleh = self.BLEH_IF_METHOD
        else:
            params.bleh = self.BLEAH_IF_NOT_METHOD
        if force:
            foobar = some_foo_bar(model_name = 'foo bar')
        else:
            default = Default()
```

Then in the child class, just override the values of the two class attributes and use the inherited method as-is.

```
class Child(Base):
    BLEH_IF_METHOD = 'child bleh'
    BLEH_IF_NOT_METHOD = 'not child bleh'
```